# In Drupal how to redirect from ?q= to clean URL using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal

Please read carefully before marking as duplicate.

I'm managing a drupal site and I was asked to make the URLs clean.

So I created the `.htaccess` file and enabled clean URLs as described in the drupal documentation. This was all easy and works fine.

The problem is that there are Thousands of intern links manually added (containing the nasty `?q=`, previous web-master was a bit...).

I don't want to edit all these sites it's just too much.
That's why I prefer to just add 2 or 3 `.htaccess` lines.

A example of the redirect would be:

```
http://www.tuteorica.com/?q=galeria/via/clases
to
http://www.tuteorica.com/galeria/via/clases
```

So far I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*=)$
#RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{query_string} q=(.*)
#RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

The commented lines are those I'm trying to make work. Is it even possible? am I in the right direction?

I know this isn't the best solution, I just want it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
#non www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R]
#/?q=foobar to /foobar

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?q=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Could you put this together with the rest of the lines, I don't want to mess things up because of wrong order? Thanks. And is there a way to make it safe for non ASCII characters?

Comment: the previous version produced a 500 server error, but now it's fine. Thanks @starkeen.